# Move array in array to parent array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Deposit] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 63393
                        [amount] => 200.00
                        [date] => 2014-06-17 08:40:13
                        [details] => 
                    )

                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [username] => presido490
                        [group_id] => 1
                    )

            )
    )
```

How to move  [username] => presido490 from [User] => Array() to  [Deposit] => Array() , i need output like that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Deposit] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 63393
                    [amount] => 200.00
                    [date] => 2014-06-17 08:40:13
                    [username] => presido490
                    [details] => 
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 1
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: You can't just delete your old question and post it again.  Your original question was deleted by you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415488/copy-array-in-array-to-parent-array-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in a simple loop

```
foreach($dataas $key => $element) {
    $data[$key]['Deposit']['username'] = $data[$key]['User']['username'];
    unset($data[$key]['User']['username']);
}
```

you could do it in an array_walk() or array_map() instead of a loop if you'd prefer

**EDIT**

If you absolutely have to position `username` between `date` and `details` (suggesting you don't really understand how to use array data in the first place).

```
foreach($dataas $key => $element) {
    $data[$key]['Deposit'] = array(
        'id' => $data[$key]['Deposit']['id'],
        'amount' => $data[$key]['Deposit']['amount'],
        'date' => $data[$key]['Deposit']['date'],
        'username' => $data[$key]['User']['username'],
        'details' => $data[$key]['Deposit']['details'],
    );
    unset($data[$key]['User']['username']);
}
```

But this should make no difference to your code at all, other than adding overhead

Comment: can we move  [username] => presido490 above [details] =>

Comment: Yes, by rebuilding the entirety of the `Deposit` suparray; but there's no valid reason why you should need that level of positioning